# How to replace the title of the profile in the breadcrumb, by the name of the user?

Tags: views, 8, users, breadcrumbs

I installed the "Profile" module. I have rewritten the url with the username instead of the profile title.

When I visit a profi, the url is corect but the breadcrumb is still indicating the title of the prodil.

How to replace the title of the profile in the breadcrumb, by the name of the user ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can implements this hook in a custom module or in your theme.

```
hook_preprocess_breadcrumb()
```

Then you can access `$variables` and manage it easily (like put the username in the last element of the array).
Regards,

Comment: @Ichabrand thank you. can you give me an example with the "Profile" module and the user name to replace the title ?